# Change output format of audio file of Audio Capture

Tags: android, audio, record, audio-recording, audioformat

I'm new to Android coding and trying to develop basic apps and I need help with the following question.

I'm trying to create an [Audio Capture App](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) using Media Recorder API's and I have a doubt regarding the output file format.

As per the code, the output file format is set to **3gp** and uses an AMR audio encoder.

```
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
```

I want the output file format to be in **mp3**. Can anyone help with this?

There are only few format as per the documentation [WEBM, THREE_GPP, MPEG_4](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html).

Please elaborate your answer as I'm new here.

Comment: That's because there's no MP3 encoder included with Android. You'll have to look for a 3rd party solution if MP3 is a must. Otherwise, just use the AAC encoder in an MPEG_4 container.

Comment: @Michael if I change extension of audiorecordtest from **3gp** to **mp3**, I'm getting an **mp3** file. Why is that?

Comment: Whether or not a file is an MP3 file has nothing to do with the file extension.